# Is there a way to detect a link in a message? (or can someone help me with my code)

Tags: python, api, request, discord, discord.py

Hey I'm currently working on a NSFW detection discord bot. But now I'm stuck i know how to scan attachements but I have a problem with my link detection I want that the bot doesn't send the api request if the message doesn't end with the arguments in `image_types`. But atm the bot sends a api request for every message someone send. I hope ya'll understand what i mean and can help me.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import os


class NSFW(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        
        image_types = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "jfif", "tiff",
                       "nef", "ai", "orf", "indd", "eps", "cr2", "psd"]
        for type in image_types:
            if message.channel.is_nsfw():
                return
            elif any(type.endswith(image) for image in image_types):
                r = requests.post(
                    "https://api.deepai.org/api/nsfw-detector",
                    data={
                        'image': f'{message.content}',
                    },
                    headers={'api-key': os.environ["DEEPAPI-KEY"]}
                )

                nsfw = r.json()
                nsfw_score = nsfw['output']['nsfw_score']
                print(nsfw)
                print(nsfw_score)
                if nsfw_score >= 0.80:
                        await message.delete()
                        await message.channel.send(
                            f"{message.author.mention} This image is to {nsfw_score:,.2f}% nsfw (0.1=10%)")
                        db["count"] = db["count"] + 1
                else:
                    return
            else:
                return


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(NSFW(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple coding error it seems ;)

You are iterating over image_types (for type in image_types) and then you are comparing it to the same values in any(type.endswith(image) for image in image_types).

That's the reason it will always return true.

Comment: Btw, I would recommend you renaming type in image_type or something similar, since type is a python built-in and naming variables the same as built-ins is generally considered a bad practice ;)